# Pass multiple javascript arrays to PHP page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was trying to find an answer for this question for a while but no luck.

The problem is this. On one PHP page i have multiple javascript arrays (lets say 2). One of those arrays is an array that represents pieces of a shirt and the other array contains color of each piece.

```
  $pieces[0] = 'base';
  $pieces[1] = 'sleeves';
  $pieces[2] = 'pocket';

  $colors[0] = 'white';
  $colors[1] = 'red';
  $colors[2] = 'black';
```

On top of all that i have a form with where user can enter some data.

Now my question is, how can I pass those two arrays and form data to a PHP page?

Thanks for all your help.

/**************
EDIT

********/

Well in case that someone has the same problem the solution is to serialize the arrays, insert them in a hidden field on a form and deserialize it on a PHP page

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/414334-pass-javascript-arrays-to-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get your question as you appear to have listed a PHP array there and not a Javascript one.

### Passing as one array from JS

```
var pieces = [
    "base",
    "sleeves",
    "pocket"
];
var colors = [
    "white",
    "red",
    "black"
];
var send_array = {
    "colors": colors,
    "pieces": pieces
};
$.post('/my/url.php', send_array); //using jQuery for ajax request
```

### Extracting json array in PHP

```
$send_array = json_decode($json, true);
```

### Passing as one array from PHP to JS

```
$pieces[0] = 'base';
$pieces[1] = 'sleeves';
$pieces[2] = 'pocket';

$colors[0] = 'white';
$colors[1] = 'red';
$colors[2] = 'black';

$send_array = array(
    'colors' => $colors,
    'pieces' => $pieces,
);
$json = json_encode($send_array);
```

Comment: Oh it's just the way I define javascript variables. I'm just starting to learn javascript/jQuery and the dollar sign is a kind of PHP habbit. Thanks for the help I'll try to do something with the code although it's not working the way I want it. I need to get those arrays AND form data on a different PHP page. Thaknks

Answer (score 3):

You can create a json of those two arrays and pass it to PHP. In PHP you can use `json_decode()` to get all the data.

eg:

http://codepad.org/r683RvsO

```
<?php

/* this json is received from javascript using ajax*/

$receivedJson =
'{
  "pieces" : ["base","sleeves","pocket"],
  "colors": ["white","red","black"]
}' ;

$infoArr = json_decode($receivedJson,true);

var_dump($receivedJson);

?>
```

Comment: Well still...I'm not sure what to do with the code but thank you for the help, have an upvote. I needed to pass those arrays and form data to a different PHP page, and I'm not sure how to do that. But thank you for your time, I'll have to look into json more thourighly.